# how to refer specific form - jquery2

Tags: jquery

If i have number of forms and I want my js refer to specific one - the one that was submitted, how can I do that?

```
<form method="post" action="#" >
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button href="#" data-ref="<?PHP echo $chatID ?>">Send</button>
</form> 

<form method="post" action="#" >
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button href="#" data-ref="<?PHP echo $chatID ?>">Send</button>
</form> 

<form method="post" action="#" >
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button href="#" data-ref="<?PHP echo $chatID ?>">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: give `id's` to forns and call using jquery. it is just basic

Comment: consider this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1urdezfa/

Comment: without ID. can i do THIS to the form that was submitted?

Comment: yes you can. Just need to give `submit()`. Check answer below.

Comment: @Santhucool - where below? i don't see...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can give each form an id and call them using jquery, or go the unconventional route and make each on into a variable using the getElementBy methods.

```
<form id="num_one">...</form>
<form id="num_two">...</form>

<script>

jquery:
$('#num_one') = form_one;
$('#num_two') = form_two;

js:
var form_one = document.getElementById('num_one').value;
var form_two = document.getElementById('num_two').value;

</script>
```

Comment: without ID. can i do $THIS to the form that was submitted?

Comment: @user6256769 answered down please check link.

Comment: you would need a way to call a specific form since they're all form tags, thats why id's or classes are necessary.

Answer (score -1):

just give `ids` and proceed it is very basic. please refer fiddle [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1urdezfa/2/)